# Can we find an asymptotically consistent Metropolis-Hastings estimator based on this proposal scheme?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, asymptotics, unbiased-estimator, metropolis-hastings

I'm running the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm for a target distribution $\hat\mu$ (see below for the formal setup including the definition of $\hat\mu$) on a product space $I\times E'$. I'm using the following proposal scheme: Given the current state $\tilde x=(i,x')$, pertrub $x'$ to $Z'\sim\tilde U(\tilde x,\;\cdot\;)$. Let $\tilde z:=(i,z')$ and $y:=\varphi_i(z')$ ($\varphi_i$ is a bijection mapping the sample from $E'$ to another space $E$). Sample $j\sim\tilde T(\tilde z,\;\cdot\;)$ (so that $j$ is sampled with propobability $w_j(y)$). Let $y':=\varphi_j^{-1}(y)$ and finally propose $(j,y')$.

Let $(\tilde X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}=(S_n,X'_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be the chain generated by the algorithm, $(\tilde Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}=(T_n,Y'_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ denote the corresponding proposal sequence and $X_n:=\varphi_{S_n}(X_n')$, $Y_n:=\varphi_{T_n}(Y_n')$, $\hat X_n:=(S_n,X_n)$ and $\hat Y_n:=(T_n,Y_n)$.

> I'm searching for an asymptotically consistent (unbiased) estimator for the integral $\lambda g$ of $\mathcal E$-measurable $g:E\to[0,\infty)$ which makes use of $Y_n$, whenever the weight $w_{S_{n-1}}(Y_n)$ is positive, and $X_{n-1}$, otherwise. Maybe something like $$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N\left[\left(1-w_{S_{n-1}}(Y_n)\right)\rho_1(\hat X_{n-1},\hat Y_n)g(X_{n-1})+w_{S_{n-1}}(Y_n)\rho_2(\hat X_{n-1},\hat Y_n)g(Y_n)\right]}{\sum_{n=1}^N\rho_3(\hat X_{n-1},\hat Y_n)}$$ for suitable functions $\rho_i:(I\times E)^2\to[0,\infty)$. Any idea how we need to choose them?

**Formal setup**: Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space
- $I$ be a finite nonempty set
- $p,q_i$ be probability densities on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ for $i\in I$
- $\mu:=p\lambda$
- $w_i:E\to[0,1]$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable for $i\in I$

Assume $$\{p=0\}\subseteq\{q_i=0\}\subseteq\{w_i=0\}\;\;\;\text{for all }i\in I\tag1$$ and $$\bigcup_{i\in I}\{q_i>0\}=\{p>0\}\subseteq\left\{\sum_{i\in I}w_i=1\right\}\tag2.$$ Now let

- $(E',\mathcal E',\lambda')$ be a measure space
- $\varphi_i:E'\to E$ be bijective and $(E',\mathcal E)$-measurable with $$\lambda'\circ\varphi_i^{-1}=q_i\lambda\tag3$$ for $i\in I$
- $\zeta$ denote the counting measure on $(I,2^I)$
- $$\tilde t((i,x'),j):=\left.\begin{cases}\left(w_j\circ\varphi_i\right)(x')&\text{, if }(w_i\circ\varphi_i)(x')>0\\|I|^{-1}&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}$$ for $(i,x')\in I\times E$ and $j\in I$ and $$\tilde T(\tilde x,\;\cdot\;):=\tilde t(\tilde x,\;\cdot\;)\zeta\;\;\;\text{for }\tilde x\in I\times E$$
- $u':E'\times E'\to(0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E'\otimes\mathcal E'$-measurable with $$\int\lambda'({\rm d}y')u'(x',y')=1\;\;\;\text{for all }x'\in E'\tag4$$ and $$U'(x',\;\cdot\;):=u'(x',\;\cdot\;)\lambda'\;\;\;\text{for }x'\in E'$$
- $\hat Q$ denote the transition kernel with density $$\hat q((i,x),(j,y)):=q_j(y)\tilde t\left(\left(i,\varphi_i^{-1}(x)\right),j\right)u'\left(\varphi_j^{-1}(x),\varphi_j^{-1}(y)\right)$$ for $(i,x),(j,y)\in I\times E$ with respect to $\zeta\otimes\lambda$
- $\hat\mu$ denote the measure with density $$\hat p(i,x):=w_i(x)p(x)\;\;\;\text{for }(i,x)\in I\times E$$